# Run 3 parallel threads in a single core machine

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, arm

I have a question to ask. I have a program (Process 1) which has three threads:

1. Thread 1 runs continuously, receives packets from a lock socket (AF_UNIX, NON_BLOCK) and copies them to a buffer.
2. Thread 2 reads from the buffer and writes the information received to a file (disk).
3. Thread 3 compresses the file if the file grows larger than 5 MB

There is another process (Process 2) which is continuously sending packets to the local socket read by Process 1. Number of packets (of around 100 bytes) sent per second can be as high as 3000-5000 packets per second. This setup runs on an embedded hardware with ARM v9 controller.

I have to ensure that the none of the packets are lost and all of them are written to disk. With the current implementation, I receive sending errors at Process 2 from "sendto" (Resource unavailable) every now and then.

I disable all locks and mutexes for avoiding race conditions (remove all checks to prevent write while read and vice-versa), even then I get sending errors from "sendto".

Then in the second step, I disable the writing to disk. Now, the Thread 1 of Process 1 can read as fast as possible from the local socket and there is no sending error. My guess is that since the threads are running on an ARM controller with no hyperthreading, there is only one thread executing at a single point of time and OS is handling the scheduling of threads.

My question here is,

Is it possible to run the three threads in parallel (each of them executing simultaneously) ? Is there a gcc construct or a compiler flag which can force the running of threads in parallel (in foreground) ? Can I change something in the program to achieve the above without splitting the functionality into multiple programs and using a shared memory for buffer ?

Regards,
Anupam

Comment: Is asynchronous I/O an option? You're probably waiting for disk until the network buffers fill up, writing the file asynchronously may help with keeping the buffers as low as possible.

Comment: unfortunately, I have also tested with huge buffers of the order of 50 MB and the buffers were not even half full when the sending errors started.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can't force any kind of thread order.  So your first question, is it possible for them to execute simultaneously?  Yes.  How can you do it?  You can't.  The operating system chooses to do that.  You can set priorities and things like that, but I still think linux (or windows) will switch threads pretty randomly and without telling you/allowing you to change the scheduler.  Think about all the threads from all the programs running on your computer; which ones can execute and when?  The answer is, who knows!  There is no way to tell when your thread will block, even if its holding a lock (which is why you're getting a resource busy response probably).  So how do you stop this from happening?  Make sure you check to see if the resource is still locked before trying to use the resource! Then, it doens't matter when the threads lock a resource.

Also, if its IPC, why are you using sockets?  Why not try a pipe, and then it doesn't matter if you lock it(unless more than one thread writes to the resource at a time).

Comment: Local Sockets are actually more flexible than pipes (e.g. sending and receiving both ways). 

And the locking is on the buffer not on the local sockets. 

I hope I have made things clear.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Sender is faster than Receiver so the NON_BLOCK option on the socket may cause the send error (returns error when sender needs to block). I have the following 2 suggestions

1. In Sender (Process 2) you can resend the packets which are resulted in send error.
2. Remove NON_BLOCK option on the socket.